# Displaying clicked items in session array

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, session

I'm learning MVC and Symfony2 (version 2.7) by creating a super simple shopping cart test (I know symfony has a doctrine for this but I just want to learn basics, so go easy on me ;) ).

All I want to be able to do is for each item they click, it appears next to the other items they clicked. This really isn't a MVC or Symfony2 problem as much as it is a php, twig coding problem that I'm flubbing on.

I have a form that users can click buy, on which users are redirected to another form that displays what they bought. Below that display are other items with the buy button option again. Once they click that button for an item, the new item should appear next to the previous one.

Instead the old item goes away and the new item appears.

How can I make the old ones stay along with the new ones?

Below is the controller class that renders the forms. *Take a look at buyAction*
It stores the items in cart, but only one at a time...How can I fix that?

//////////////////

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use AppBundle\Entity\Item;
use AppBundle\Form\ItemType;

/**
 * Item controller.
 *
 * @Route("/item")
 */
class ItemController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Lists all Item entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="item")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entities = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Item')->findAll();

        return array(
            'entities' => $entities,
        );
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Item entity.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="item_create")
     * @Method("POST")
     * @Template("AppBundle:Item:new.html.twig")
     */
    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $entity = new Item();
        $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('item_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
        }

        return array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to create a Item entity.
     *
     * @param Item $entity The entity
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createCreateForm(Item $entity)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new ItemType(), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('item_create'),
            'method' => 'POST',
        ));

        $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create'));

        return $form;
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to create a new Item entity.
     *
     * @Route("/new", name="item_new")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function newAction()
    {
        $entity = new Item();
        $form   = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

        return array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        );
    }


    /**
     * Displays Bought Items
     *
     * @Route("/buy/{id}", name="item_buy")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function buyAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Item')->find($id);

        $entities = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Item')->findAll();

        $cart = [];

        $session = $request->getSession();

        $session->set('cart', $cart);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('No Item ');
        } else {
            $cart[$entity->getId()] = $entity->getName();
        }

        $session->set('cart', $cart);

        return array(
            'cart' => $cart,
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'entities' => $entities,
        );
    }


    /**
     * Finds and displays an Item entity.
     *
     * @Route("/show/{id}", name="item_show")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function showAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Item')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Item entity.');
        }

        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

        return array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to edit an existing Item entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="item_edit")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function editAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Item')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Item entity.');
        }

        $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

        return array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
    * Creates a form to edit a Item entity.
    *
    * @param Item $entity The entity
    *
    * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
    */
    private function createEditForm(Item $entity)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new ItemType(), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('item_update', array('id' => $entity->getId())),
            'method' => 'PUT',
        ));

        $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Update'));

        return $form;
    }

    /**
     * Edits an existing Item entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="item_update")
     * @Method("PUT")
     * @Template("AppBundle:Item:edit.html.twig")
     */
    public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Item')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Item entity.');
        }

        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
        $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
        $editForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($editForm->isValid()) {
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('item_edit', array('id' => $id)));
        }

        return array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an Item entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="item_delete")
     * @Method("DELETE")
     */
    public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $form = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entity = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Item')->find($id);

            if (!$entity) {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Item entity.');
            }

            $em->remove($entity);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('item'));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to delete an Item entity by id.
     *
     * @param mixed $id The entity id
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createDeleteForm($id)
    {
        return $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('item_delete', array('id' => $id)))
            ->setMethod('DELETE')
            ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Delete'))
            ->getForm()
        ;
    }
}
```

/////////////////
Below is the first form, where nothing is "bought" yet. 
//////////////////

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body -%}
    <h1>Item list</h1>

    <table class="records_list">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for entity in entities %}
            <tr>
                <td><a href="{{ path('item_show', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">{{ entity.id }}</a></td>
                <td>{{ entity.name }}</td>
                <td>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ path('item_buy', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">Buy</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ path('item_show', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">show</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ path('item_edit', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">edit</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="{{ path('item_new') }}">Create a new entry</a>
            </li>
             {#<li>
               <a href="{{ path('item') }}">Buy Item</a>
            </li>#}
        </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

/////////////////////
Below is the form users are shown after they "bought" an item (where the "bought" item is displayed up top) and where they can choose to "buy" something else (where this new item should go next to the previous "bought" item).

////////////////////

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body -%}
    <h1>Items Bought...</h1>

    <table class="record_properties">
        <h3>You Bought...</h3>
        {# {% if entity is defined %} #}
            {% for entities in cart %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ entity.name }}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        {# {% endif %} #}


        <tbody>
        {% for entity in entities %}
            <tr>
                <td><a href="{{ path('item_show', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">{{ entity.id }}</a></td>
                <td>{{ entity.name }}</td>
                <td>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ path('item_buy', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">Buy</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>


     <ul class="record_actions">
    <li>
        <a href="{{ path('item') }}">
            Back to the list
        </a>
    </li>
{% endblock %}
```

//////////////////////

I've been starring at this all day yesterday and I can't find my issue. So any help is appreciated, thanks.

ALSO
Any ideas how to make this better/things to help me learn MVC basics/Symfony2 stuff would be cool if you got some too. I've been using Lynda dot com, google, this site, the Symfony book/cookbook. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have this in your last Twig file.

```
{% for entities in cart %}
```

You're placing in entities variable each iteration of cart, so you're losing all entities loaded in the controller.

Change this...

```
{% for entities in cart %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ entity.name }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

to this...

```
{% for cartItem in cart %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ cartItem.name }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

At least this part should be solved :)

Comment: Check that your Item entity has a way of accessing name (getter, public property...)

Comment: it does, it shows up in my second for loop in the same twig file